# How to create timed transition in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a timed transition in Qt (C++) and this is driving me nuts. I have three "LEDs" that are illuminated on the UI. When the user clicks a button, I want them to die sequentially, like [this](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/d/d/b/ddb77385127229b13ba6cc68d97d6a317e6c8663.gif) but in reverse:

I have this function that is called when the button is pressed (this is the slot):

```
void MainWindow::turnOff(int i){
    while(i>0){
        QTest::qSleep(250);
        changeBrightness(i);
        qInfo("\n\n\at easeOff %d", brightness);
        i--;
    }
}
```

and the changeBrightness function:

```
void MainWindow::changeBrightness(int i){
    if(i > 0 && i <= 20){
        ui->LED1->setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: black; }");
        ...
    }
    brightness = i;
}
```

The console shows the value changing, but the actual UI transition only happens at the ends (all the LEDs go off at once). Brightness is a value between 1 and 100. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Qt Creator is just the IDE. The library is called Qt. Since your question has nothing to do with Qt Creator, I'm removing that tag.

Comment: You could try to manually call `ui->LED1->repaint()` on LED after you change its brightness. Also, I don't recommend using qSleep() as it hangs your UI. Try to use `QTimer::singleShot()` to schedule your changeBrightness event.

Comment: If this with `QTimer` works well for you, great, but you may consider looking into `QPropertyAnimation`. With that class you can implement this with a lot of control over start/stop/speed and even the animation curve. The other advantage is that your animation speed would not be fixed to 250ms and so could be smoother potentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sophryshko's suggestion of the repaint() function worked!

```
void MainWindow::turnOff(int i){
    while(i>0){
        QTest::qSleep(250); 
        ui->LED1->repaint();
        changeBrightness(i);
        qInfo("\n\n\at easeOff %d", brightness);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help. Will add the QTimer object as well but this was sufficient to change the UI behavior.